# transfer in Miami, final destination Charlotte, where do I clear customs?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, stopovers

I'm gonna fly from Barcelona to Charlotte with a stop in Miami. I wanted to know if I'll need to get through the US Customs and Border Protection in Miami, because I have a flight to take from Miami to Charlotte, and the waiting between my flights it's 1:36 hours. Or if I'll pass through it once I get to Charlotte, where I need to take my luggage and take a domestic flight.

It's the second time I'm flying to the States (first in 2008), and I have an ESTA.

Comment: Is this one ticket? 1:36 seems very short for a connection from a long haul flight through customs and immigration.